# Devise rememberable is remembering nothing

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I'm implementing Devise on a Rails 3.2 application and want the system to remember the user.

/app/models/user.rb:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me
end
```

/db/schema.rb:

```
create_table "users", :force => true do |t|
  t.string   "name"
  t.string   "email"
  t.string   "password"
  t.datetime "created_at",                             :null => false
  t.datetime "updated_at",                             :null => false
  t.string   "encrypted_password",     :default => "", :null => false
  t.string   "reset_password_token"
  t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
  t.datetime "remember_created_at"
  t.integer  "sign_in_count",          :default => 0
  t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
  t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
  t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
  t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
end
```

I'd like to do this in the most standard/default way, and given the shortage of documentation, I'm guessing that it "just works" for some people and simply isn't working for me. For example, I used the Devise generator to build the migration for User, and haven't overridden any controllers. I get a check box, but when I check it, the user's info is not remembered.

What am I missing? Is there something missing from my schema which the generator was supposed to create?

Comment: I think Devise lacks a lot of Doc on this issue. We don't know if putting rememberable as a strategy in User is enough or not. And if it is enough why doesn't it work when the browser is closed even though session variable still has user info.

Answer (score 0):

try to play with

```
current_user.remember_me = true
current_user.remember_me = false
```

your schema.rb looks correct.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is what you meant-

According to [Module: Devise::Models::Rememberable](http://rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/Devise/Models/Rememberable) devise's `:rememberable` is used to save the login credentials of the user who is currently logged in. This means it will remember the credentials if you close the browser and do not log out.

However this will not save your login credentials (email, password) if you log out.